# Rhino Mocks - Mocking collection with ref/out arguments

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I'm still learning Rhino mocks and have a question about it. For example - I have a function in mocked interface:

```
    public interface ISomeObject
    {
      string Name {get; set;}
      int Id {get;set;}
    }

    // This class will be returned as and answer to function call
    public class AnswerObject
    {
        public bool IfError {get;set;}
    }

    // Main interface
    public interface IClass
    {
        AnswerObject FunctionGetCollection(ref ICollection <ISomeObject> ListOfInternalObjects, ref int Number);
    }
```

As you see the function 'FunctionGetCollection' will receive 2 parameters passed as 'ref' and return another class as 'function-answer'. Can you help me to stub this funciton ? I need to be able to use:

- function will return different collection (based in place in code not on parameters)
- function will return different AnswerObject

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is not very nice. It is not used very often and uses the old-style `Rhino.Mocks.Constraints`.

This piece of code sets up a mock that replaces all the ref-arguments with new values.

```
AnswerObject answerObject;
ICollection <ISomeObject> collection;
int number;

IClass iClassMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IClass>();
iClassMock
  .Stub(x => x.FunctionGetCollection(
    ref Arg<ICollection <ISomeObject>>.Ref(Is.Anything(), collection).Dummy,
    ref Arg<int>.Ref(Is.Anything(), number).Dummy);
  .Return(answerObject);
```

If you want to keep the values as they are passed to the mock, you need to implement this in a WhenCalled block:

```
iClassMock
  .Stub(x => x.FunctionGetCollection(
    ref Arg<ICollection <ISomeObject>>.Ref(Is.Anything(), null).Dummy,
    ref Arg<int>.Ref(Is.Anything(), 0).Dummy);
  .WhennCalled(call =>
  {
    // reset the ref arguments to what had been passed to the mock
    // not sure if it also works with the int
    call.Arguments[0] = call.Arguments[0];
    call.Arguments[1] = call.Arguments[1];
  })
  .Return(answerObject);
```

Comment: Is.Anything - gives an error: 

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Rhino.Mocks.Constraints.AbstractConstraint'

(I also add the 'ref' before Arg<> parameters as function require)

:( :(

Comment: That's correct answer - use Is.Anything() in both places and add 'ref' before 'Arg<>' and it works ! I was close anyways :) :)